# How should an application parse a list of filenames from cmdline args?

Tags: parsing, filenames, cmdline-args

I'd like to write an app, my_app, that takes a list of named options and a list of filenames from the cmdline, e.g.,

```
% my_app --arg_1 arg_1_value filename_1 filename_2
```

The filenames are the last args and are not associated with any named options.

From the cmdline parsers, e.g., *flag* in Golang, that I've worked, it seems that the parsers will only extract the args that are configured, and that I'd need to identify the list of filenames manually by walking thru the original argv[] list.

I'd like to ask if there are parsers (or their options that I may have overlooked) that can also extract those filenames, or they only return the unprocessed args, and therefore, I could assume that these are the filenames.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if it had some specifics, like the language you are using.

Comment: I've edited the question to include flag for Golang as an example

Comment: Ok, i tried an answer. But I'm a bit puzzled: the function hands you a slice consisting of precisely the arguments you want. What more could it possibly do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Golang `flag` module makes the trailing arguments available as the slice `flag.Args`, which is the trailing part of `os.Args`.

That's a pretty typical way for command-line argument parsers to work, although the details will vary according to language. The standard C library argument parser, fir example, provides the global `optind`, which is the index in `argv` of the first non-flag argument.

Comment: thank you! flag.Args in Golang and optind in C are exactly what I was looking for.